# Android things UsbDevices

Tags: android-things

I am developing with Android Things on **rpi3**.
I have a problem working with usb devices(pendrive) in my Raspi3 on Android things platform 1.0 Versión, i have been able to detect Usb(pendrive) Files, and copy files to them from my sd Card. 
I use '`com.github.mjdev:libaums:0.5.5`' library, and  I cannot work with all kind of usb devices.I have 3 pendrives which are FAT32, and i can only use one, the others report me an error message, as soon as i plug them into mi rpi3, i get this messages:

> - "Unsupported fs on partition"
> - "E/2: error setting up device"

So i cannot work with them, because the error appears on `setup_device()` functions of this library.

Any idea?

Best regards 
Álvaro

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, I do not think I will be able to help you out on that one.

You should make sure it is FAT32 and an MBR (GPT is not supported, atm).

If that is the case then please debug and see why the Fat32FileSystem cannot be initialized properly.

Comment: It is FAT32 and MBR the error appears on this metthod: public static Partition createPartition(PartitionTableEntry entry, BlockDeviceDriver blockDevice), any idea of other ways of using usb  mass storage device on Android Things?

Comment: I have made last commit of develop Branch work, importing it as a module and not compiled in the gradle, with some sticks it works, but others still fail, reporting : "Unsuccessful Csw status: " + csw.getbCswStatus()); of file ScsiBlockDevice.java, any idea?@Magnus

Comment: I have checked and all of them are fat32 and MBR

Comment: this is the error stacktrace:7-20 06:11:09.200 2229-2229/com.usb E/2: error setting up device
    java.io.IOException: Unsuccessful Csw status: 1
        at com.github.mjdev.libaums.driver.scsi.ScsiBlockDevice.transferCommand(ScsiBlockDevice.java:185)
        at com.github.mjdev.libaums.driver.scsi.ScsiBlockDevice.init(ScsiBlockDevice.java:98)
        at com.github.mjdev.libaums.UsbMassStorageDevice.setupDevice(UsbMassStorageDevice.java:232)
        at com.github.mjdev.libaums.UsbMassStorageDevice.init(UsbMassStorageDevice.java:192) i always get same error with some usb sticks

Comment: Hi!, i solved the problem, just need a delay before calling discover function and all usb sticks work.